# Model building based on preliminary data analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model

I have a extremely simple data set which consists of one independent variable (five sampling sites as factors) and the outcome variable which is disease status (positive/negative) in crabs from each site. These sites are located at varying distances from a sewage outfall point. My hypotheses are that 1) prevelence is different among sites, and 2) disease prevalence varies as a function of distance from an identified point-source pollution area.
Hypothesis 1 was tested using a chi-square test for trend. Regarding hypothesis 2, I built a logistic regression model. Instead of using as a reference group the site located farthest away from the pollution source (least exposed crabs), I resorted to a preliminary analysis and used the site with the lowest prevalence as the reference group. Having said that, I did not choose my baseline category (against all other are compared) *a priori*, but only after knowing that crabs from that site are the least affected ones. It made biological sense to me to build the model that way; however, I am not sure that I am not violating any assumption here by not including as reference category the one which I thought would have the lowest disease prevalence in the first place. Am I making a big mistake here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might be able to do an ANOVA for part 1 and a grouped linear regression (by distance) for the other. Is there a flow or current component to this? That is, are the sites upstream/downstream or upcurrent/downcurrent from each other? If so, the function by distance may not be anything like linear.

Comment: Thanks! However, AFAIK, for the ANOVA I would need a continuous response, which I don't... my response variable consists of ceroes and ones (binomial).